# Problem reprojecting KML in EPSG:2039 Map - OpenLayers 2.12 + proj4js

Tags: openlayers-2, proj

I have KML files (EPSG:4326) and a background map I made using EPSG:2039 projection (mandatory).

When I try reprojecting the KMLs to show in EPSG:2039 I don't succeed and still they don't appear on the map. Only when manually projecting everything to EPSG:4326 its working (But I need to be in EPSG:2039 for the client)

```
 init: function () {

    var transperantLayers = ["kml1", "kml2", "kml3"];

    var P2039 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2039");
    var P4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

    var activeProjection = P2039;

    OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;

    var options = {
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508, 20037508, 20037508.34),
        projection: activeProjection,
        displayProjection: P4326
    };      

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", options);

    var base = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapInfoRESTHandler("Background", "MapTileServer",
                            { mapname: "Background", output: 'image/png', tileType: 'MBR', transparent: false },
                            { isBaseLayer: true, buffer: 1, transitionEffect: 'resize' });

    map.addLayer(base);

    for (var i = 0; i < transperantLayers.length; i++) {
        var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(transperantLayers[i], {
            projection: map.projection,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "KMLs/" + transperantLayers[i] + ".KML",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true,
                    extractAttributes: true
                })
            })
        });
        layer.setOpacity(0.5);
        map.addLayer(layer);
    }

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(220000, 632000), 9);        

}
```

I've also tried instead of :

```
projection: map.projection
```

doing :

```
projection: map.displayProjection
```

but still no luck... not seeing the KMLs.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:
I just noticed there wasnt epsg2039.js file in the def directory.
I've added it and now it works.